# Parse log file using grep or awk

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, grep

I have a [log file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWTR23/ch2log.htm). Example of output looks like this:

`...
10-MAY-95 14:16:21*(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=reltest)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\ORAWIN\BIN\PLUS31.EXE) (HOST=WINDOWSPC)(USER=CCLOW))*(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=144.25.23.246)(PORT=3366))*establish*reltest*0
...`

Log parameters are entered in the appropriate component configuration files in the form: 
`log_parameter_component = value`

So, goal is to parse the above output and display result only with key=value, key=value, etc:
`log_parameter_component = value, log_parameter_component = value, etc.`

The result should look as following after parsing:

`...
SID=reltest, USER=CCLOW, HOST=144.25.23.246
...`

How to solve this task?

Comment: Why `PROGRAM=C:\ORAWIN\BIN\PLUS31.EXE` should not appear ? Or `PROTOCOL=tcp` ?...

Comment: It was just example. It would be great if you can give an example with all key=values.

Comment: Can you please tell how the above example should look like in the  output?

Comment: SID=reltest, USER=CCLOW, HOST=144.25.23.246

Answer (score 0):

This should work in `perl` but I admit the second part could probably be avoided:

```
perl -p -e 's/.*?\(([^()]+?)=([^()]+?)\).*?/$1=$2,/g' myfile.log | perl -p -e 's/(.*),.*/$1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Found very close soulution.](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1752498)

But, how script will be look like if I want to add some additional patterns? If I will use awk script?
Ex. only for: SID, USER, SERVER, HOST.